# RegExp - Finding words not starting with a certain char

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to extract words (read: functions) from a string with RegExp and pass them to a PHP function.

The following works pretty well already:

```
$func = preg_replace("/(\b.+\b)/Ue", 'extract_functions(\'\\1\')', $oneliner);
```

While it extracts existing functions from the string it also extracts variables with the same name, but without the starting `$` char.

So if the string contains an existing function named `get_function` it also extracts a variable named `$get_function` but without the starting `$`, so I can't be sure whether I have a function or variable extracted.

My idea was to exclude words starting with `$` but that doesn't seem to work:

```
$func = preg_replace("/[(\b[^\$].+\b)/Ue", 'extract_functions(\'\\1\')', $oneliner);
```

I'm out of ideas...

Comment: Could you show some sample input strings and expected result?

Comment: See here: http://regex101.com/r/vD6nQ0#PCRE In this script, it gets `current_action` as a result, even though it's only existing as `$current_action` in the string, never as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jeff, here's the solution that works for me:

```
$filecontent = file_get_contents($file); // Parsing the file's contents into a string
$re = '/(?<!\$)(\b\S+?\b)(?=\()/'; // The pattern
preg_match_all($re, $filecontent, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

print_r($out[0]);
```

I'm using a *negative lookbehind* as suggested by Jeff as well as a *positive lookahead* checking for a `(` after each word, but without making the `(` part of the match.

I went for the `(` part as that defines a PHP function as far as I'm concerned.

I'm open for improvements! :-) Thanks to Jeff!

Comment: Ahh, if function names are all followed by `(`, then yes, that's the way to go. Though now, you might remove the ungreedy flag: `$re = '/(?<!\$)(\b\S+\b)(?=\()/';` which works exactly the same way but a little shorter :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookbehind to make sure that there's no `$` preceding your function/variable:

```
$func = preg_replace("/(?<!\$)(\b.+\b)/Ue", 'extract_functions(\'\\1\')', $line);
```

By the way `[(\b[^\$]` is a bit wrongly formed. You have a character class containing `(`, `\b`, `^` and `$`, which doesn't work. It will actually match any of those characters instead of not matching a `$` character.

It would have been a little closer with `/[^$](\b.+\b)/` but this one might not work at the beginning of strings.

Comment: Hi Jerry, I read about negative lookbehinds too, and now that you mentioned it, I was happy at first, but that doesn't seem to make any difference. I'm still getting the exact same results with or without the negative lookbehind part. I did check twice, and there's no function `get_function` in the string but a variable `$get_function` and I get the result that `get_function` is present in the string, even though it isn't.

Comment: @Alphawolf Hi! Um, could you perhaps give a sample of your input string? Maybe there's a better workaround? Functions and variables cannot contain spaces, right? Maybe `(?<!\$)(\b\S+?\b)` would be more adequate? [regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/jR3xA3)

Comment: Hmmm. Seems like it's working indeed: http://regex101.com/r/vD6nQ0#PCRE However, in my script, I still get `current_action` as a result, even though it's only existing as `$current_action` in the string, never as a function. Investigating... Thanks so far, Jerry! :-)

Comment: @Alphawolf Okay, I won't be around for a while (timezones ^^;) I'll be checking up here in a few hours :)

Comment: Well, time for zZz's here, too (9:49pm here). ^^

Comment: @Alphawolf Oh wow, I just checked the sample through your previous link and there's quite some work left to hone the regex. Hmm, do let me know how it goes.